# QMap. Ошибка при выводе значений, соответствующих ключам

Tags: c++, qt

Помогите с проблемой. Ошибка где то во втором цикле снизу. Там програма должна вывести все значения, которые соответствуют ключам. При запуске програма выводит несколько элементов и начинается аварийное завершение. В чем же тут дело?

```
void find(const QString& directory_path) {

    QDir dir(directory_path);
    QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList();
    QByteArray arr;
    QMap <QByteArray, QString> hash;
    QFileInfo fileinfo;
    int count, count2;

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        fileinfo = list.at(i);

        if(fileinfo.isFile()) {
            QFile file(directory_path + "/" + fileinfo.fileName());
            if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
                arr = file.readAll();
                file.close();
                hash.insertMulti(arr, fileinfo.fileName());
            }
        }
        if(fileinfo.isDir() && fileinfo.fileName() != "." && fileinfo.fileName() != "..") {
            find(directory_path + "/" + fileinfo.fileName());
        }
    }

    QMap <QByteArray, QString> ::iterator iter = hash.begin();
    QMap <QByteArray, QString> ::iterator iter2 = hash.begin();

    for(iter = hash.begin(); iter != hash.end(); iter++) {
        count++;
        for(iter2 += count; iter2 != hash.end(); iter2++) { //ОШИБКА В ЭТОМ ЦИКЛЕ
            if(iter.key() == iter2.key()) {
                count2++;
                if(count2<1) qDebug() << iter.value() << endl << iter2.value();
                else qDebug() << iter2.value();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш код и завершилось без ошибок искал в D:\\Program Files -- там немного файлов и папок

Может, у вас слишком много уровней рекурсии было? А что нужно по заданию? Если просто получить все файлы, можно и QDirIterator использовать

Да и если, честно, я не понимаю вторую часть кода -- после     QMap <QByteArray, QString> ::iterator iter = hash.begin();

Comment: Програма должна искать дубликаты файлов в заданой директории и всех ее подкаталогах и выводить эти файлы. Сначала я ищу файлы и заливаю в QMap, где за ключ принимаю бинарное содержимое файла (QByteArray arr) а за значение беру название файла. Вот во второй части програмы я и реализую поиск одинаковых файлов по содержимому.

Comment: Накладно хранить все содержимое файла, я бы брал от содержимого хеш -- памяти больше останется, да и проверка будет быстрее

Comment: Так а если заливать в хеш несколько раз один и тот же ключ, то значение одного элемента просто будет изменятся тоже несколько раз. Разве нет? Если да, то как мне потом проводить проверку на равность?

Comment: Посмотрите мой вариант :) Несколько топорно -- торопился

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считываем содержимое файла и хешируем его `MD5` – это контрольная сумма файла. *Особенность хеш-функций в том, что для одних и тех же данных они сгенерируют один и тот же результат, но если данные изменятся, даже на 1 байт, то хеш совершенно будет отличаться.* Вот это свойство хеш-функций мы и использовали, чтобы находить файлы с одинаковым содержимым.

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QCryptographicHash>

void findFilesDuplicate(const QString& directory_path) {
    QMap <QByteArray, QString> hashMap;

    QDirIterator iterator(directory_path, QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();

        const QString& filePath = iterator.fileInfo().absoluteFilePath();
        QFile file(filePath);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
            continue;

        QByteArray hashMd5 = QCryptographicHash::hash(file.readAll(), QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex();
        hashMap.insertMulti(hashMd5, filePath);
    }

    QSet<QByteArray> unicKeys = QSet<QByteArray>::fromList(hashMap.keys());

    foreach (const QByteArray& key, unicKeys) {
        const QList <QString>& files = hashMap.values(key);
        if (files.size() > 1) {
            qDebug() << key << files;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как вариант, создать словарь у которого ключом будет хеш содержимого файла, а значением -- список файлов: QMap <QByteArray, QList<QString> > hashMap;, тогда можно не заморачиваться над добавлением одинаковых ключей и использования множества для получения уникальных ключей :)

Comment: Элегантный способ. Все просто и удобно. Но вот я не могу понять строку кода: QByteArray hashMd5 = QCryptographicHash::hash(file.readAll(), QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex(); могли бы вы пояснить пошагово, что тут происходит?

Comment: Считываем содержимое файла и хешируем его [MD5](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) -- это контрольная сумма файла. Особенность хеш-функций в том, что для одних и тех же данных они сгенерируют один и тот же результат, но если данные изменятся, даже на 1 байт, то хеш совершенно будет отличаться. Вот это свойство хеш-функций мы и использовали, чтобы находить файлы с одинаковым содержимым

Comment: @gil9red, вынесите описание того, что Вы сделали в ответ. В комментариях это будет сложно найти, пусть будет в ответе. А то просто простыня кода это не очень хороший вариант ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Во втором цикле вы используете неинициализированную переменную `count`. Вы предполагаете, что её значение на первой итерации цикла равно 0, но ни  стандарт, ни компилятор этого не гарантирует. Поэтому после инструкции `iter2 += count` разыменование итератора `iter2` даёт неопределённое поведение. Что вы и наблюдаете в виде падения программы из-за нарушения обращения к памяти. Для интереса проверьте в отладчике значение `count` в строке `count++`.

Да и вообще, Ваш циклический перебор уж очень странно выглядит. Переписал так:

```
QMap<QByteArray, QString>::const_iterator it = hash.begin();
QMap<QByteArray, QString>::const_iterator end = hash.end();

for (; it != end; ++it) {
  QStringList filenameList = hash.values(it.key());
  if (filenameList.size() > 1) {
    qDebug() << filenameList.join(",");
  }
}
```

И последнее. Сейчас ваш код ищет совпадающие по содержимому файлы в одной директории. Для всех вложенных директорий выполняется та же процедура. Т.е. всегда сравниваются друг с другом файлы, лежащие в одной директории. Это приводит к тому, что если файл `dir/subdir/file.txt` является копией файла `dir/file.txt` в выводе вашего кода вы этого не увидите.
Рекомендую, сначала рекурсивно пройтись по директории и по всем вложенным в неё директориям, собрав все файлы в **один** контейнер. И только потом этот контейнер обработать.